# $_GET variable not staying set when set with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

sorry i am new to ajax and well programming in general.

I have a set of divs each containing a set of products for an e-comm site. Only one div is visible at a time when a certain stock button is clicked.

when a user clicks on a product displayed inside the visible div the user is taken to a new page where the product details are displayed. Basically What i'm trying to do is have a history when the user clicks the back button in the browser, i want it to return to the last div that was visible when the page is loaded.

I am trying to use ajax to send a variable to a php file when the user opens a product div, and then retrieve that variable when the user clacks back and the  page reloads. I can send the variable fine with ajax to the php file and return with the success property of the same ajax function. But after that, when i try to retrieve the variable, it appears as unset.

**Ajax send method:**

```
    // when the user clicks the apparel stock button the corresponding div becomes visible 
    $("#stockApparel").click(function(){

      var $apparel = "apparel";

      $.ajax({

          url: "php/panel.php",

          data: { panel: $apparel },

          type: "get",

          dataType: "text",

          success: function(response){
              alert(response); // response is "apparel" as intended/
          },

      });


      $("#stockButtons").animate({left: '1140px'});
      $("#new").animate({left: '-470px'});
      $("#apparel").show(700);
      $("#marketing").hide(100);

      var divPosition = $('#shippingImg').offset();
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "slow");

  });
```

**Get method to retrieve variable**

```
$(window).load(function(){
         alert('window has been fully loaded');

        $.get("php/panel.php", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); // returns as "variable not set".
        });

     });
```

**Php file**

```
if (isset($_GET['panel'])) { // check if varaiable has been set

    $panel  = $_GET['panel'];
    switch ($panel) {
        case "collectable":
            echo "collectable";
        break;

       case "apparel":
           echo "apparel";
       break;

       default:
    }
 } else echo "Variable not set."; // if variable is not set

?>
```

even if i put the $.get method directly after the ajax send method i still get the "Variable not set" returned from the php file, any ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering for this question straightly: **no, get parameters don't stay on server-side between requests**. 
However, *you might want to read some basics of client-server interactions*.
 In two words: in first case you send GET request with some parameters
`panel.php?panel=value`
 in second case - it is just plain GET request without it. Server does not keep information about previous requests himself and does not have to. If you wanna keep this information, you might want to use some sort of database logic, or session/cookie caching (there is a answers, that provide code examples of this).

Answer (score 0):

Http is stateless. You need to temporarily persist that information so that you can return it when user request it again (page reload).

You may use session variable to persist it and read it from that and return it in your server page.

Something like this, (I am not a PHP person, But you get the idea ?)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['panel'])) {
  // to do : check $_GET['panel'] before setting to session
  $_SESSION['panel'] = $_GET['panel'];
} 
return $_SESSION['panel'];

?>
```

Comment: I will try, i had previously tried using sessions instead of ajax to do this and run a <script> in the php file. but for some reason   only the first two lines of code would run    $("#stockButtons").animate({left: '1140px'});
      $("#new").animate({left: '-470px'});
      $("#apparel").show(700);
      $("#marketing").hide(100); ... the last two would not run

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of panel:

```
$.get("php/panel.php",{panel:'apparel'}, function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); // should get the panel variable now..
});
```

Comment: unfortunately i was hoping to have the value of panel changed when a user open a new product div, so setting the panel value to the $.get method would not work as the panel value is meant to change.

Comment: then `{panel: $('.your_div_element').val()}` should solve the issue of changing the input by user.